# Is there a way with Grunt to automatically link css files to HTML

Tags: html, css, gruntjs

I am just wondering if there is a way to automatically link css files to HTML. For example just give the files (dependencies) path and it will be automatically stylesheet link to the specific HTML file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSS is in a Bower package, you can use [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep): just include

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

in your html, and wiredep will replace it with links to the CSS from your Bower packages.

If your CSS is your own, as far as I know there is nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand your question .. What did you mean with automatically? If I understand this in the right way, this question should be in the PHP-rubric (or other server-side languages). If you want to include a CSS-File in a HTML-document, you have to declare the following line in the header of your HTML-Document:

```
<link href="example.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When you create the header of your page, you could write a PHP-function to include the CSS-Files and pass the reference as a param. :)

Excuse my bad english ..

Comment: i'm asking if grunt can do that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you .. I honestly don't have any experience with this framework.